# My profession is written "Unemployed" on my passport. Will it have a bad influence on getting a student visa?

Tags: visas, passports, study

I left my job recently, applied for a passport, and declared my profession "unemployed". Now, as I want to study abroad, Will it give a wrong impression to the visa officer that my profession is unemployed? Will they consider me as an unqualified person because of my written profession?

Comment: Most countries do not mention professions on passports, I doubt most countries would even consider what is written there but why did you not mention your last profession (or study) when applying?

Comment: As you do not have a question about a previous visa refusal that tag does not apply. The tag that is needed is your nationality, as that might make a difference. And study visa are one country visa, so the tag Schengen visa is also a wrong one. The country you are hoping to study would be much better.

Comment: *Usually* the universities, not the visa or immigration office, decide on whether you are qualified for a program and do not rely on your passport data. Most students are not professionally employed or become unemployed upon commencement of studies.

Comment: The big issues for the visa issuing country are (a) whether you can pay for the trip, and (b) that you have sufficiently strong ties to your home country that you'll leave the visa-issuing country when the visa term is over. Many questions and answers on this site address these issues. Using the "Search on Travel" box at the top of the page, search for "Home Ties" and "visa refusal."

Comment: Qualification requirements for a visa depend on the country, but if you are unemployed you are unemployed. What is written on your passport does not change the fact and how this fact contribute to the processing of your visa. If you become employed or matriculated you may provide additional evidences (e.g. letters from employers or school, salary statements or tuition receipts) to support the change in circumstances.

Comment: Why wouldn't a student be employed? Surely that indicates a good reason to study. It would be a Catch-22: *I can't get a visa to gain a qualification because I don't have a qualification.* But really, with "I left my job recently" you should have put your actual job/profession.

Comment: @xngtng Sure, universities may decide whether you are qualified or not, but universities do not issue the visa. Ultimately, it's an immigration officer which issues the visa, and she takes several things into account, of which the university's decision to consider the candidate qualified is one. She *will* take a look at that passport. (Whether she cares about the mentioned occupation is something else)

Comment: @WeatherVane Lots of university students have never been employed, especially not in the field they intend to pursue for their career. At least here in the U.S., the vast majority of college students are right out of high school.

Comment: @reriab I guess you could paraphrase my comment as "Being unemployed indicates a good reason to study." I think the ticks show other folks understood it.

Comment: @WeatherVane did you mean: Why *wouldn't* a student be *un*employed?

Comment: @reriab "Why wouldn't a student be employed?" Because they never had a job. You are splitting hairs

Comment: @WeatherVane typically a student's "profession" is listed as "student" though

Comment: @Esther perhaps, but the OP does not. The question is about 'unemployed'.

Comment: Note for the future: profession and job are different things. You may have a job without it being your profession (you are an engineer, or a student, but you work as a dishwasher, or as an uber driver), or you may have a profession not matching any available job (for example being a hangman in Germany).

Answer (score 29):

Probably not. At most it represents what you were doing at the time you applied for a passport.

For future reference your profession does not have to be the job you have now, but your normal career. If you regularly work as an engineer but currently do not have a job, or have taken a break to study, you can still give your profession as "engineer".

Answer (score 3):

I would think it depends on what country you want to study in **and** what country you are coming from.  If you’re going from USA (3½% unemployment) to Spain (12½%), the person handling your application might think you’re planning to work illegally.  But going the other way, they might not.

Comment: Historically the opposite is more true--if a place has low unemployment then it is more willing to welcome new people because they can become employed and contribute to the economy. Vs. the same place with high unemployment can't support the people it currently has and is less welcoming of new people. (Note I'm comparing the same place at two unemployment levels, different areas have...call it a baseline tolerance to new people, a place with high unemployment offset by a high baseline may still be more welcoming than a place with low unemployment and a low baseline.)

Comment: @user3067860: That argument would be relevant to the number of work visas issued.  OP is applying for a student visa.  Even when there is a need for more workers, they need the correct visa category.

Comment: Yes, I inadvertently typed it backward.  Fixed.  But I disagree the argument applies to a work visa.  If you are applying for a work visa, there's no reason for anyone to assume you plan to work illegally.  But it is conceivable that someone might dishonestly apply for a student visa when they really want to get a job.  And it is conceivable that an official might assume dishonesty where none exists.  My son was denied entry to Canada as a tourist with the alleged reason of "I think you're trying to immigrate and work illegally."

Comment: @WGroleau Hmm... The way you had it the first time makes more sense to me. Why would someone want to migrate from a place where jobs are very easy to get to a place where they're very hard to get to work illegally? Illegal work immigration is usually the other way around (i.e. the way you had it the first time.)

Comment: Side note: Unfortunately, the USA is a bad example for this example, since there's a lot of xenophobia about immigrants taking job away from citizens. And that xenophobia has nothing to do with unemployment rates or how many jobs are available. The US Immigration officers might not have a problem with what's written on a passport, but hiring managers, college/university administration depts., or people who have absolutely no reason to look at your passport might.

Comment: None of those people will look at your passport when you are _applying_ for a student visa.

Comment: @reirab: The question is about applying for a _student_ visa.

Comment: @WGroleau Right, but there's virtually no incentive for someone in a place with low unemployment and high wages to fraudulently apply for a student visa in order to attempt to find a job in a country where jobs are much harder to find and/or pay is lower than their home country, whereas there's lots of incentive for people to fraudulently apply for non-work visas (including student ones) in order to immigrate to countries with low unemployment and/or higher pay.

Comment: I don't think OP is worried about that.  He/she asked whether being unemployed would be a problem for his student visa application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it might be a problem. I know a guy from Croatia whose visa application for USA was rejected 3 years ago because he was unemployed. So it depends where do you want to go and what is your citizenship.

Comment: Was that guy applying for a study visa or for a short visit? Students who stay in a country for most of a year do not usually keep a job in the country they came from.

Comment: Yeah, this very much depends on the type of visa being apply for. If you're applying for a tourist visa to the US, but you're unemployed, don't have much savings, and can't demonstrate much in the way of things tying you to want to stay in Croatia (i.e. owned property, family, etc.,) they're going to be much more skeptical of both your intent to be only a tourist to the U.S. who will leave before visa expiration and also your ability to afford staying in the U.S. for your visit compared to someone who has a well-established job, family, property, etc. in Croatia with significant savings.

Comment: He applied for tourist visa. He had appointment in US embassy and guy told him that he doesn't have job, wife or any reson to return back to Croatia. He didn’t know how to respond, and visa was denied.

Comment: @andrija: In other words, it didn't matter one iota what the passport said. He'd be rejected just as fast if his passport would have listed a previous profession.

Comment: There are no strict rules and they have no obligation to give you explanation. Sometimes they just reject visa, you ask why and they refuse to answer. Even if you have visa, when you get to border they can refuse to let you in. You don't have any rights in this case. You have to take this risk.

Comment: Unemployed and going to the US on a tourist visa? I am quite sure they would have thought the guy was going to look for a job - which is prohibited on a tourist visa - so they actually thought that refusing a visa to this person was a good thing to prevent him doing something illegal!